# Azure Service Bus The binding type(s) 'serviceBusTrigger' are not registered for python function

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Hi I am getting below issue,this is a python function

"

The binding type(s) 'serviceBusTrigger' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed."

My function.json:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "queuest",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsAzureSBConnection"      
    }
  ]
}
```

My extensions.csproj file is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <WarningsAsErrors></WarningsAsErrors>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>**</DefaultItemExcludes>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="3.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.24" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this problem, this is caused by the incomplete extension.

[image]

In local you don't need the `extensions.csproj` file, you should set the host.json content, following this doc: [Extension bundles for local development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-register#extension-bundles)

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
    }
}
```

**Note**:If you already have this value in the host.json, go to `C:\Users....\AppData\Local\Temp\Functions\ExtensionBundles` delete `ExtensionBundles` folder. Then restart your function, it will download the extension. Then it should work.

Comment: Thanks George, I have already find this solution and it is working